# Inverse Percentage.

Tags: math-software, average, computational-mathematics, percentile

Sorry for asking this foolish question.

Here is the data i have.
I purchased the product as `$5 and additional fee is 2%.`
So Here is the total dollor 
`$total = 5 + (5*2/100) = 5.1` `total dollor` i have.
But now i want to revert back to original price

```
in this case i have the data as only 
total amount

$5.1 and 2% fee.
```

How can i revert back to `$5` based on the above data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your calculation that the additional fee is $2$ **percent** of the price, not $\$2$. That means that if the base price is $p$, the total cost $t$ is $t=p+0.02p=1.02p$. Thus, $p=\frac{t}{1.02}$.

In your example, for instance, this leads to the calculation

$$p=\frac{5.1}{1.02}=5\;,$$

as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian. can you please explain me 1.02 value. So far i got is 2/100 = 0.02 how it goes to 1.02?

Comment: @User: You have $$p+0.02p=1\cdot p+0.02\cdot p=(1+0.02)\cdot p=1.02p\;.$$ It’s just using the fact that $ap+bp=(a+b)p$.

Comment: You Freaking Genius !!! Thanks For your Wonderful info. Much Appreciate your Help

Comment: @User: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let the original amount be $x$.

Then, $x+x\left(\frac{2}{100}\right)=5.1$

which gives $x=5$.